# SEVERE: The web application [solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat]

Tags: tomcat8

The following information appeared in my catalina.out logs for tomcat8

WARNING: Skipped session attribute named [javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale.session] because the value type [java.util.Locale] did not match the filter [null]
ноя 01, 2023 6:20:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [solr] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ThreadLocalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ThreadLocalDateFormat@7bacd6a0]) and a value of type [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField.ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat] (value [org.apache.solr.schema.DateField$ISO8601CanonicalDateFormat@6b2ed43a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
ноя 01, 2023 6:20:32 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

I tried to increase the heap size but it didn't give any results